# django-filter with DRF does not JOIN filter fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Hi I'm having a weird issue with using 'django-filter' alongside the Django Rest Framework to filter an API.

If I use the following queryset it works as expected:

`queryset = Project.objects.filter(assignments__user=self.request.user,assignments__role__name="Manager")`

My Projects model has a ManyToMany relationship with Assignments. Each assignment has a user field (FK to User model) and a role field (FK to a ProjectRole model). When I run this queryset I get back all Projects where the current user is assigned AND the role is Manager.

When I try to acheive the same with the django-filters plugin however, it seems like I get back an OR joined expression (even though this should not be the default behaviour):

```
class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('assignments__role__name','assignments__user')


class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.all()
        return queryset

    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = ProjectFilter
```

I setup two filter fields for user and role, I get back every Project where within its assignments there is at least one assignment where the user is assigned (with any role) AND there is at least one assignment with a Manager role. However it does not check that this is 1 assignment, so I get back projects where current_user is a 'ReadOnly' role and user2 is 'Manager' role.

Comment: How did you pass the `self.request.user` (user PK) to the filter?

Comment: I'm using the API for an AJAX call with datatables, calling it from the template HTML file like so: table.ajax.url('{{ base_url }}/project/api/projects/?assignments__operator={{ request.user.pk }}&assignments__role__name=Manager&format=datatables');

Comment: @ArakkalAbu that will be the user instance, and not the PK. You need to add `.pk` for that.

Comment: I now understand that it gets all Projects where within all assignments there is at least one assignment for the current user AND one assignment with a Manager role. So it does use AND just not the correct constraint.